# How do I convert monthly data into quarterly

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a data set that I need to convert from monthly to quarterly data.

This is the first five lines of my data.

```
                   Measure Name             Year    Month   Value
0   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Jan $1,757,000
1   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Feb $2,052,000
2   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Mar $2,747,000
3   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Apr $2,308,000
4   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    May $2,289,000
```

I don't know where to begin with this to convert the from monthly to quarterly.

```
Jan-Mar will be Q1
April-June will be Q2
July-September will be Q3
October-December will be Q4.
```

I looked into creating a Chort group analysis but because my time data is in two columns I don't know where to start.

Here is my code so far

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report
plt.style.use(style='ggplot')

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

recycle=pd.read_csv('Pathway link',
                       sep=',',)
```

I am expecting `2007 Jan-Mar` to to be `Q1` and so on....

Answer (score 0):

You could tackle this in a number of ways, the first is to think of Months as numbers, and apply some logical test statements. For example `if month <= 3 THEN QTR = 'Q1'`

but it seems you're dealing with strings and not datetime objects so we can try passing the months into a dict and having the Quarter as the value pair. Of course this is contingent on your months being the same as the keys.

```
months = { 'Jan' : 'Q1',
      'Feb' : 'Q1',
      'Mar' : 'Q1',
      'Apr' : 'Q2',
      'May' : 'Q2',
      'Jun' : 'Q2',
      'Jul' : 'Q3',
      'Aug' : 'Q3',
      'Sep' : 'Q3',
      'Oct' : 'Q4',
      'Nov' : 'Q4',
      'Dec' : 'Q4' }

df['Qtr'] = df['Month'].map(months)
print(df)
    Measure Name    Year    Month   Value   QTR
0   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Jan $1,757,000  Q1
1   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Feb $2,052,000  Q1
2   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Mar $2,747,000  Q1
3   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Apr $2,308,000  Q2
4   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    May $2,289,000  Q2
```

you can then apply your group by aggregation :

```
df.groupby('QTR')['Value'].sum() 
#you'll need to convert your value into a number if its an object.
QTR
Q1    6556000
Q2    4597000
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```